# javascript remove remove values from array smaller then value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array in javascript like this (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) and i want to remove al the values that are smaller than 5. So the array that remains is (1,2,3,4). How to do this with javascript or jquery...

Comment: Your question conflicts with itself, please reword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to remove items larger than 5, but jquery grep should do it:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Comment: if you don't want to load the big jquery libary, use underscore instead. in underscore the right method is named _filter. http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the array  with [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

var new_array = array.filter(function(item) {
    return item < 5;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TSQu8/)

or if you have to support IE8 and below, you can do it the old fashion way

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    new_array = [];

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 5) new_array.push(array[i])
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TSQu8/1/)

Comment: xD jup. i forget about it. but yes, he's right. but be aware of browser compatiblity with nativ filter method. have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/). This will remove values less than 5 and remaining array values will be removed from array.

```
var arr = $.map( [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ], function( n ) {
    return n < 5 ? n : null;
});
console.log(arr);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hzq9h/)**

or

Use [`.grep()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/). This will remove values less than 5 and remaining values will be removed from the array.

```
var arr = $.grep( [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ], function( n ) {
    return n < 5;
});
console.log(arr);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Hzq9h/1/)**

I will suggest you to go with grep based on jsperf result.

http://jsperf.com/map-vs-grep/2

Comment: you are not removing the wrong values you just change these values to null. but they are still there. better is $.grep() or .filter()

Comment: @ManuelRicharz: Could you please check array length it is showing 4. Hope map will work.

Comment: yes, the length is not counting null-values. but the memory is still allocated.

Comment: @ManuelRicharz: jQuery's map function is different than the native map function. It removes the array element if the callback returns `null` or `undefined` (see the documentation). And of course `null` values are considered for `length`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var newarr = [];
For(var i=0 ; i<=arr.length ; i++){
    if(arr[i] < 5){
       newarr.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use *JavaScript* is good in compare of *jQuery*. Because *JavaScript* *Execution* fast compare to a *jQuery*.

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vEfZ5/1/)**</kbd>

#### JavaScript

```
var filtered = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].filter(issmall);

function issmall(element) {
    return element < 5 ;
}    

console.log(filtered);
```

#### Result

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

JavaScript [**filter()**](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/core-javascript-reference/the-array-object/array-filter) Method

Answer (score 0):

```
var orig= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

just in case they're out of order:

```
var copy=orig.sort();
```

then:

```
var result = copy.splice(0,copy.lastIndexOf(4)+1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LXaqe/